# how to setRowdata with complex objects

Tags: ag-grid

I have this columndefs
[image]

But the source of data is this array. 
[image]

So I only see projectId and projectName in the grid. 
[image]

Is it possible assign this array or I might change his structure?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to set the data through the `setRowData` method of ag-Grid API, you have to make sure, that either of data entry is consistent between any other.

You can try to consider the following ways to solve this.

1. **Data transformation on back-end side**
   It might be the case if you are full of control over the back-end API, just send right back to the client the data in the most appropriate way for you.
2. **Splitting the process of setting data from `setRowData`**
   You may want to introduce some additional methods for your component with data-grid e.g. one for setting `projectId` and `projectName` and another for setting `calendarValues`. ag-Grid [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/) offers up to 4 different ways of updating the data.
3. **Defining custom `valueGetter` for each column**
   You can try to modify definitions for `columnDefs` by introducing custom `valueGetter` which would take care of extracting appropriate value e.g.

```
  const columnDefs = [
    {
      headerName: "Febrero2019",
      field: "Febrero2019",
      valueGetter({ data: { calendarValues } }) {
        return calendarValues['Febrero2019'];
      }
    },
  ];
```

4. **Preprocessing data that comes from the API**
   In your case, you can define a tiny little helper function that would handle the process of transforming raw data from the API into an appropriate format of data acceptable for `api.setRowData` method.

```
const colDefs = [
    { headerName: 'Codigo', field: 'projectId' },
    { headerName: 'Nombre', field: 'projectName' },
    { headerName: 'Febrero2019', field: 'Febrero2019' },
    { headerName: 'Marzo2019', field: 'Marzo2019' }
];

const projectData = {
    calendarValues: [
        { date: 'Febrero2019', value: 0 },
        { date: 'Marzo2019', value: 0 },
    ],
    projectId: 'SomeId',
    projectName: 'SomeName'
};

const processData = ({ projectId, projectName, calendarValues }) => ({
    projectId,
    projectName,
    ...calendarValues.reduce((calendar, { date, value }) => ({ ...calendar, [date]: value }), {})
});
```

so the call `processData` will result in the desired data format.

```
{
  Febrero2019: 0
  Marzo2019: 0
  projectId: "SomeId"
  projectName: "SomeName"
}
```